# Removing the white bar in barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Im trying to remove the white bar on the right of this barplot, but i cannot understand how.
Here is the graph:

[image]

Here is the code i used:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x=`neighbourhood`, y="1", fill=`room_type`)                                                                    
 geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity") +
 coord_flip() +
 scale_fill_brewer(palette = 14) +
 labs(title = "Tipi di stanze per quartiere", y = "Quantità", x = "Quartiere", fill = "Tipo di stanza")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Difficult to say without a reproducible example, but try `y = 1` instead of `y = "1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `y = "1"` and the `stat = "identity"`, like this:

```
library(ggplot2)    
    ggplot(data = df2, aes(x=`neighbourhood`, fill=`room_type`)                                                                    
     geom_bar(position="fill") +
     coord_flip() +
     scale_fill_brewer(palette = 14) +
     labs(title = "Tipi di stanze per quartiere", y = "Quantità", x = "Quartiere", fill = "Tipo di stanza")
```

Comment: Thanks! the problem was in fact `y = "1"`. Have a great day